# Get rows from database using the Entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework

I have created a .mdf database file. I have created a table like in the picture below:

[image: Table]

I'm trying to use Entity framework, to communicate with the database.

Here, I'm using a context to connect to the database:

```
namespace SportsStore.domain.Concrete
{
    //Associate the model with the database
    //This class then automatically defines a property for each table in the database that I want to work with. 
    public class EFDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here, I'm trying to get the rows from the database:

```
namespace SportsStore.domain.Concrete
{
    public class EFProductRepository : IProductRepository
    {
        private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

        public IEnumerable<Product> Products
        {
            get { return context.Products; }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run my application, nothing is printed out. The rows from the database are not printed out.

Worth not notice is that when I start my application, a red arrow is shown above the SportsStore.mdf like the picture below:

[image: Table]

Should I add something to Web.Config? If so, what should I add?

Comment: Red arrow is shown because connection is made to database, so outside environment has tried to use this database

Comment: is your connection string is proper?

Comment: @Arvaan: I have not added a connect string to my Web.Config. Should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It seem you have no connection for Entity Framework in web.config look like

```
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="ManageCustomersEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entities.Model1.csdl|res://*/Entities.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Entities.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=YOURSERVER;initial catalog=DBNAME;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=******;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /> </connectionStrings>
```

And then set connection for **EFDbContext**

Hope it helps!

Comment: @Lewis_Hai: Where should I put this line In the config-file?

Comment: @Bryan: Web config of your web application.

Comment: @Lewis_Hai: But where In the config-file? When I paste the line inside <configuration></configuration> I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

you can get table rows via Entity Framework:

```
public class BlProduct
{
    public List<Product> Select()
    {
        EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();
        try
        {
            return (from a in context.Product Select a).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

it's fair to call this class.

Comment: are u sure that namespaces are mentioned on the header? otherwise append using (EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext()){ //Code Behinde// }

Comment: Should I not add a line In Web.Config?

Comment: First you must make the model Then within your webconfig connection string was created. Follow : https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/getting-started-with-ef/the-entity-framework-and-aspnet-getting-started-part-1

Comment: Having already established a database connection even just replace the name of the table and model